# Samples to use when calculating SHAP values

Tags: random-forest, shap

I'm new to data science and I'm learning about SHAP values to explain how a Random Forest model works.

I have an existing RF model that was trained on tens of millions of samples over a few hundred features. Also, the model tries to predict if a sample belongs to Class A or B, where the proportion is heavily skewed towards Class A, like 1000:1.

I've read that calculating the SHAP values can be slow when there are a lot of samples and features. And I've come across `shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)` where `X` can be the entire dataset, or just `X_train`, or `X_test`.

So my questions are

1. I guess the SHAP values will be different for `X`, `X_train` and `X_test`, but the general feature importance and their contribution to the prediction would still be very similar?
2. Because I'm working with such a large and skewed dataset, I'm thinking of just calculating the SHAP values of a sampled dataset. If I take just 1% of samples belonging to Class A and B each, thus preserving the proportion (I'm afraid just randomly sampling the entire dataset would result in too few Class B samples), would this give me a reasonable global interpretation of the model?
3. The model was trained some time ago using a dataset that may no longer be available to me. Can I calculate the SHAP values using a more recent dataset that is similar to the old data, or do I need to use the exact dataset that was used to train the model?